# Unwanted Scrollbar error in Magento

Tags: magento, scrollbar

I Installed Magento and a theme from envato . However it was working with out any issue and at some point of time it started giving an additional unwanted verical scrollbar in my template

Please check the URL : http://shoptwiz.com/about-shoptwiz   with 2 scrollbar on the right hand side .

Can any one point out the problem ?![enter image description here][1]

http://oi61.tinypic.com/29ftphy.jpg   Screen shot Link

I have tried to disable or comment http://www.shoptwiz.com/skin/frontend/default/ves_superstore/css/styles.css

at line 4378

overflow-x: hidden;

which removes the scroller . But this gives out another bug . 
There is unusual Gap below the footer and the footer of website do not stick to its place .

This is a screen shot after i try to edit css from firebug

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2s8pd9w.jpg

Any one with a good advice ???

Answer (score 0):

Thats a css issue. overflow property problem. I think they have set(theme providers) multiple time the same property. Anyway just open the below file,

```
http://duwj1c2q9eaye.cloudfront.net/skin/frontend/default/ves_superstore/css/styles.css
```

at line 4378 remove or comment this css property

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

That's it. If you have any doubt comment here.

Comment: I did it , It did not worked . ! I am using cloud front cdn will it take some time ?

Comment: remove your cache from var/cache/ or from admin -> cache management

Comment: It did not helped , instead it destorted rest of the website css . I had to restore backup taken by me .

Comment: It should be worked. I have checked using firebug. You May be made  syntax error in your css file during edit or browser cache or your magento system cache. Clear all cache things and check again.

Comment: Yes it did remove the scroller but there is still a large gap after footer of website . I think generally the footer should stick t to the bottom